# How to convert Observable<byte[]> to Observable<String>?

Tags: java, string, utf-8, rx-java

I'm reading stdout of an Process using `process.getInputStream()`. I wan to create an observable that will spew out Strings.

With `StringObservable.from(process.getInputStream())` I'm getting `Observable<byte[]>`. How to translate it in-flight into partial Strings ?

I have found https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/String-Observables#decode but have no idea how to use it. Text is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Hows your Observable defined?

Comment: StringObservable.from(process.getInputStream())

Comment: You can use `public static Observable<String> decode(Observable<byte[]> src, String charsetName)`, such as `StringStringObservable.decode(StringObservable.from(process.getInputStream()), "UTF-8")`

Comment: I copied the comment to the answer to help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `public static Observable<String> decode(Observable<byte[]> src, String charsetName)`, such as `StringStringObservable.decode(StringObservable.from(process.getInputStream()), "UTF-8")`